# Handling QSqlTableModel data on startup

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qsqltablemodel

I have an application of which I want data from an SQLite database to be parsed directly on startup.

When starting the application, I'm calling a member function of my QSqlTableModel instance called `create()`:

**mymodel.cpp**

```cpp
MyModel::MyModel(QObject* parent) : QSqlTableModel(parent)
{
}

// ...

void MyModel::create()
{
    // SQL specific
    createTable();

    setTable(myTableName);
    setSort(2, Qt::DescendingOrder);
    setEditStrategy(QSqlTableModel::OnManualSubmit);

    // config specific
    addUserEntry();

    emit myModelChanged();
};
```

I have a controller which provides `MyModel` for QML:

**mycontroller.h**

```cpp
class MyController : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(MyModel* myModel READ myModel CONSTANT)

    MyModel* myModel() { return _myModel; }

    // ...

private: 
    QSqlDatabase _database;
    MyModel* _myModel { nullptr };
};
```

**mycontroller.cpp**

```cpp
MyController::MyController(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent)
{
    _database = QSqlDatabase::database();
    // ...
    _myModel = new MyModel(this, _database);
}

void MyController::start()
{
    _myModel->create();
    // ...
}
```

The controller class is being registered for QML in my `main.cpp`:

**main.cpp**

```cpp
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // ...

    qmlRegisterType<MyController>("my.application.app", 1, 0, "MyController");

    // ...
    _myController->start();
```

and instantiated in `main.qml`:

**main.qml**

```
ApplicationWindow {
    // ...

    MyController {
        id: myController
        objectName: "myController"

        onMyModelChanged: {
            if (myModel.someValue.length > 0) {
                Config.someValue = myModel.someValue;
            }

            if (myModel.otherValue.length > 0) {
                Config.otherValue = myModel.otherValue;
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
```

Now, what I want is for my QSqlTableModel to retain data from the SQL table directly after calling the `create` function so the table model will be refreshed and accessible in QML.

E.g., I want `Config.someValue` and `Config.otherValue` in QML to be set directly after starting the application.

**How do I tell the QSqlTableModel to refresh and push data to QML even if no data was changed before?**

What I can see is when calling `QSqlTableModel::data(index(0, 0), 2).toString()`, the information is already there, however the table model *is not being refreshed in QML* but the values requested (i.e. `myModel.someValue` and `myModel.otherValue` are shown as `undefined`. How do I achieve this?

Comment: please provide a [mre]

Comment: @eyllanesc I have provided a minimal example which I hope will tell what I mean.